# Mask/remove some information from logs through Logstash filter

Tags: logstash, elk

I have configured ELK to work with IIS & Nginx logs and used the GROK filter to parse the log message. But there is sensitive data in the message field after parsing - Name, Address, CreditCard etc. Like this:

```
orderId=60490298&address1=Nam+explicabo+Ad+labore+aut+minim+duis+vitae+ipsam+elit+sit+laboris+eum+esse&address2=10&city=New+York&stateId=34&zipCode=10001&productId=10262&contentVerisonId=38660&stringOffers=%5B%7B%22Id%22%3A82965%2C%22Quantity%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D&code=&step=1&billingZip=10001&billingStateId=34&stringCartOffers=%5B%5D&allowEditCart=true
```

I have patterns for defining this data, is it possible to check the field for the presence of this data and delete it through the Logstesh filter?

PS Mask this data in NGINX is not a solution.

Comment: perhaps with the [gsub option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) of the mutate filter?

Comment: or you can use the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) (with the field_split option to &) to get fields like address1, address2 and then removing them (with the remove_field common option); or directly with the exclude_keys option of kv.

Comment: gsub option looks like the solution to my problem.
@baudsp Thank you